# WSO2 Identity Server Deactivating user account

Tags: wso2

By looking at the user account's log i see that there is a claim named "http://wso2.org/claims/accountStatus" that is displayed as a checkbox. I have enabled that claim and now i set it's value. However it does nothing except keeping the value. Is there a way to prevent a user with disabled account from login (especially login through SAML SSO login)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable login by changing the permission of the user's user group. (So add him to that
user group if you need to prevent login). You can uncheck it at the user permission tree
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS410/Editing+User+Roles

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However there should be a more proper way for disabling (even temporarily) an user account. Is there a way I could file a feature request about that?

Comment: You can use https://wso2.org/jira/ to add an improvement. Further you can use dev@wso2.com ( Mailing list supscriptions are here http://wso2.org/mail) to discuss this further in detail too.